# DidSelectItemAt Collection view issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having problem with `didSelectItemAt` in a `UICollectionViewCell`. I'm using a third party framework to select multiple photos from the library. The selected assets are then transferred and stored in a array of `PHAssets`. I use a small script for custom preview of the images when tapped on them. (It basically expands the image to full screen and put in and then you can swipe up or down to dismiss it). The problem is not with the images, they're properly displayed in my custom `UICollectionViewCell`. The problem is when I tap on them. For some reason it gives the wrong image and I'm not sure why.

```
var cameraPhotoUIImage: UIImage?
var assets = [PHAsset]()
lazy var assetsTurnedIntoImages =
{
    return  [UIImage]()
}()

lazy var imageManager = {
    return PHCachingImageManager()
}()

extension PhotoVC : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    func setupCollectionView()
    {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoPostCVCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoPostCVCell
        if let takenImage = cameraPhotoUIImage
        {
            cell.cellImage.image = takenImage
        }
        if assets.count > 0
        {
            let asset = assets[indexPath.row]
            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
            { (image, info) in
                cell.cellImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                cell.cellImage.image = image!
                self.assetsTurnedIntoImages.append(image!)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if assets.count > 0
        {
            return assets.count
        }
        else
        {
            return 1
        }
    }

    // MARK: Preview Selected Image
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let postStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard_Post, bundle:nil)

        if let destinationVC = postStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewImageVC") as? PreviewImageVC
        {
            destinationVC.allowedDismissDirection = .both
            destinationVC.maskType = .clear
            if cameraPhotoUIImage != nil
            {
                destinationVC.transferedImageToPreview.image = cameraPhotoUIImage
                destinationVC.showInteractive()
            }
            if assetsTurnedIntoImages.count > 0
            {
                print("Selected image to preview:",assetsTurnedIntoImages[indexPath.row]  )
                destinationVC.transferedImageToPreview.image = assetsTurnedIntoImages[indexPath.item]
                destinationVC.showInteractive()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is on the `requestImage` request. If your request is async then it does not wait for the block. When the operations is completed, maybe another cell is reloaded.

Comment: @ridvankucuk how it should be done correctly then? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `requestImage` method. requestImage method looks like async. So that request does not wait block to complete. If you update your block like this, it should work.

```
    imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
            { (image, info) in
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
               let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoPostCVCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoPostCVCell
               cell.cellImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
               cell.cellImage.image = image!
               self.assetsTurnedIntoImages.append(image!)
               }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. The only thing that I've removed from your code is the line with the cell initialization. (I've done it above since I have another option of an image, that its not populated by the same assets array.

Comment: Do not remove it. That's the critical part of the code. You are using the same indexPath on dequeue cell for that line.

Comment: with that line, the cell is not even being populated by the images